# Find the code line that required a file

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I would like to trace the code that caused RequireJS to fetch a file.
[image]

When clicking on the link `require.js?_b=71d1:1908` I'm passed to the requirejs script file - that does not help me find out who initiated this call.

I'm sure it's somewhere my code I just can't find out where - this is a huge project.

How can I trace the `require` call?

EDIT:
Here's a callstack when putting a break point:

You can see that none of them involve my own files.. just requirejs.
I already looked into the `require.config.js` and no dependencies on that file were found.

That's odd.

[image]

Comment: Did you try creating a breakpoint at that location in the `require.js` file and then checked the stacktrace when you reach the breakpoint?

Comment: By 'mouseover' on the `require.js?_b=71d1:1908` I can see the stacktrace - it's huge... I tried diving into some of them but couldn't find the source call.

Comment: @alesc check the post edit please

Comment: Maybe try to dive into one of the entries in the stacktrace and check local variables for potential module name that could be the culprit. Starting at the bottom would probably be the best.